# I am having Issues counting values in a row with separators using SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am new to snowflake and trying the count the number of values in a row with separators using SQL. I am not sure how to go about it. I've googled solutions for this but have not been able to find one.

table name: **Lee_tab**

| user | names |
| --- | --- |
| id01 | Jon;karl;lee; |
| id02 | Abi;jackson; |
| id03 | don; |
| id04 |  |

what I want to achieve

| user | names | name_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id01 | Jon;karl;lee; | 3 |
| id02 | Abi;jackson; | 2 |
| id03 | don; | 1 |
| id04 |  | 0 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is three solutions using [REGEXP_COUNT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/regexp_count.html), [SPLIT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/split.html), [ARRAY_SIZE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/array_size.html), [STRTOK_TO_ARRAY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/strtok_to_array.html) (I would use the REGEXP_COUNT one):

```
SELECT 
    column1, 
    column2,
    regexp_count(column2, ';')+1 as solution_1,
    ARRAY_SIZE(split(column2, ';')) as solution_2,
    ARRAY_SIZE(strtok_to_array(column2, ';')) as solution_3  
FROM VALUES
    ('id01','Jon;karl;lee'),
    ('id02','Abi;jackson'),
    ('id03','don');
```

which gives

| COLUMN1 | COLUMN2 | SOLUTION_1 | SOLUTION_2 | SOLUTION_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id01 | Jon;karl;lee | 3 | 3 | 3 |
| id02 | Abi;jackson | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| id03 | don | 1 | 1 | 1 |

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which DataBase you're using, because there are some different
things in syntax. I made your example with using SQLite Browser and I have a result like this one:

SELECT SUM(length(names) - length(replace(names, ';', '')) +1)
AS TotalCount
FROM Lee_tab where id = USER ID

As I know, in Postgres there's no **length**, it's just **len** there, so, pay an attention.

My query-it's just a formula to how count values, separated by ;
To get your result, you should learn how to join.

Answer (score 1):

Rewriting json_stattham's answer using Snowflake syntax. Basically, we are just counting the number of separators (semicolons) in the string and adding 1. There is no need to use the SUM() function as in json_stattham's answer.

```
with cte as (
    select 'id01' as user, 'Jon;karl;lee' as names union all
    select 'id02' as user, 'Abi;jackson' as names union all
    select 'id03' as user, 'don' as names
)
SELECT user, names, (length(names) - length(replace(names, ';'))) + 1 AS name_count 
FROM cte;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different answer, using the Snowflake [SPLIT_TO_TABLE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/split_to_table.html) function. This function splits the string on the delimiter, creating a row for each value, which we lateral join back to the CTE table, finally we COUNT and GROUP BY using standard SQL syntax:

```
with cte as (
    select 'id01' as user, 'Jon;karl;lee' as names union all
    select 'id02' as user, 'Abi;jackson' as names union all
    select 'id03' as user, 'don' as names
)
select user, names, count(value) as count_names
    from cte, lateral split_to_table(cte.names, ';')
group by user, names;
```

Comment: Thanks for the contribution, please If we have 100 rows how do we handle that

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer for your query

```
select user,names,(len(names) - len(replace(names, ';',''))+1) names_count from Lee_tab;
```

for more understanding check this ,i have done all
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/BQuEjw2pthMDb1z8NTdHv/0